# SQL join greater than / less then

Tags: sql, date, join, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables

[image: First]

[image: Second]

I 
So i need to get a table in which rows will be excluded for which the date for each "id" is more than in the second table "datestop"

I tried inner join with double condition:
id = id and Date < DateStop, but in this way also excluded rows which not contained in table 2 (id1)

For imagine, thats what i want to get:

[image: result]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes version & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` which is very efficient:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists ( 
  select 1 from table2 t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.datestop <= t1.date  
)
```

It's not clear if you need the value of `Status` must be `'Stopped'` for your requirement.
So maybe you need to change the `WHERE` clause of the subquery to:

```
where t2.id = t1.id and t2.datestop <= t1.date and t2.status = 'Stopped'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
left join tableb b on b.id = a.id
where b.id is null or b.datestop > a.date
```

This phrases as: get all records in `tablea` for which either there is no record with the same `id` in `tableb`, or whose `date` is less than the `datestop` of the corresponding record in `tableb`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where `all` can be helpful:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.date < all (select b.datestop
                    from b
                    where b.id = a.id and b.status = 'Stopped'
                   );
```